# why supervisord requires start again after vagrant reload

Tags: python, django, vagrant, ansible, supervisord

I am working on a python-django project where i am using vagrant and ansible orchestration tool. Inside my project I am using nginx and uWsgi server and to handle that I am using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

I gave script to start supervisor inside ansible. Its working fine for first time `vagrant up`. Also it is working fine when I suspend and resume my vagrant (using `vagrant suspend` and `vagrant resume/up` command), It works fine. (Automatically my project runs on browser). but when I gave `vagrant reload` or `vagrant halt` then `vagrant up`, My supervisor stopped. I don't know why?

Can anyone please help me? I want to run my supervisor automatically when I give `vagrant reload` as well.

Comment: Did you check supervisors logs after calling `vagrant reload`?

Comment: @daniula : When I gave vagrant reload, my previous supervisod logs gets deleted and new logs will be generated only after starting supervisord again manually.

Comment: How did you install Supervisor? If you installed it via pip, it won't have an init file to start on system boot.

Comment: I resolved this issue. I need to add runlevels to supervisord . In ubuntu we have to use **update-rc.d** and in centos we have to use **chkconfig** command to do that. chkconfig is more user friendly and easy to understand. There is chkconfig package also available for ubuntu user, Using which we can easily set runlevels.

Comment: If you resolved you issue please update this post with you answer.

Comment: @juliansalas till today not able to find the reason for the same.